# Was Apollo the exact same in Greek and Roman mythology?

Tags: greek, roman, apollo

[Apollo is Apollo.](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/a/1685/967)

So, are they the exact same in qualities in both Roman and Greek mythology?

If not, what qualities did they share?

Comment: There are definitely nuances distinct to each culture, and associations, such as with the Sun, changed over time. There are also a number of localized versiona of Apollo in Ancient Greece. When I get a chance, I'll compare the Latin with the Greek sources and get you more specifics. At a high level, I seem to recall that Apollo was more central in the Roman pantheon, and more highly regarded. By contrast, the gods in Greek myths are not very dignified--Homer made a point of juxtaposing their pettiness against the dignity of human beings, with Hector as the prime exemplar.

Comment: All the major 12 Roman Gods are the Greek Gods, renamed. [The Roman Gods still live in Olympus, their authentic home in Greece](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/740/where-did-the-roman-gods-live).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes Apollo is the same god in both Greek and Roman mythology.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo) The Roman worship of Apollo was adopted from the Greeks. As a quintessentially Greek god, Apollo had no direct Roman equivalent, although later Roman poets often referred to him as Phoebus.

A similar question was asked here: [Was Apollo the sun god in Augustan Rome?](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/1683/was-apollo-the-sun-god-in-augustan-rome)

Comment: Phoebus is a Greek name, too, and Apollo is called such in Greek as well. Same with Dionysus and Bacchus  or Pallas and Athena — all are Greek names.

Comment: So, yes? (It's a yes/no question...)

Comment: @arboviral Yes. Apollo is Apollo but was called both Apollo and Phoebus by the Romans.

Comment: I realise that; I was suggesting you edit it into the answer. I already upvoted, but strictly speaking the way your answer is written currently it doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: That answers misleads the reader to believe that not all of the 12 Roman Gods were the 12 Olympian Gods renamed.

Answer (score 4):

The Roman story was that they adopted the god Apollo from the Greeks after a plague in the 430s BCE. According to Wikipedia:

> On the occasion of a pestilence in the 430s BCE, Apollo's first temple at Rome
>   was established in the Flaminian fields, replacing an older cult site there known
>   as the "Apollinare". During the Second Punic War in 212 BCE, the Ludi Apollinares
>   ("Apollonian Games") were instituted in his honor, on the instructions of a
>   prophecy attributed to one Marcius. In the time of Augustus, who considered
>   himself under the special protection of Apollo and was even said to be his son,
>   his worship developed and he became one of the chief gods of Rome.

The Roman Emperor Augustus had a special devotion to Apollo as well, considering him a patron god. They seem to have seen Apollo as essentially the same god as the Greek version: oracular, artisitic, athletic. However, he took on a more imperial role during Augustus' time.

Answer (score -4):

Yes, Apollo is the same in both Greek and roman mythology because he is the god of poetry, light, and archery.